# Asp Core + EPPLUS How to do a page break?

Tags: asp.net, export-to-excel, epplus, asp.net-core-2.2, export-to-pdf

I am working with Asp Core 2.2 and Epplus library. I need to generate an Excel document and display titles as page divisions.

I need to make page breaks, but I don't know how to do it.

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a page break on columns or rows like this.

```
ws.Column(5).PageBreak = true;
ws.Row(5).PageBreak = true;
```

Comment: Thanks bro.. This was useful.